# HTTP conformance test suite

Tags: unit-testing, http, standards-compliance

Are there any good **HTTP** conformance test suites?

I need to test some *existing* code for the standard compliance and do not want to reinvent the wheel and bump into various corner cases.

I'm not specifying the language I use. I expect suite to be generic enough to be adaptable for my needs – although I'd settle for anything that is sane.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A Test For HTTP 1.1 Compliance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100848/a-test-for-http-1-1-compliance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know how accurate or complete it is, but [HTTP Lint](http://zamez.org/httplint) looks like it may be similar to what you're looking for?

Comment: Close enough, thanks. But I'm still looking for more complete solution. Looks like HTTP Lint does not test for e.g. reaction to bad queries etc.

Comment: Yeah, hence the question mark. I wasn't quite sure what you were looking for, but it looked like HTTP lint would do at least some of it.

Answer (score 1):

[RFuzz](http://rfuzz.rubyforge.org/) is HTTP fuzzing library for Ruby, though I'm not sure if it tests *compliance* specfically.

Comment: Quite interesting tool, thank you, I'll use it. But aside from that I really need to *specifically* test for conformance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.web-polygraph.org/. It may be what you are looking for.

Cheers

Comment: Looking at https://www.web-polygraph.org/compliance.html, the below text is stated. I do not believe polygraph is what they're looking for: `Web Polygraph cannot be used to test protocol compliance. When compliant behavior is necessary for smooth operation, Polygraph may detect protocol violations and complain about them. However, in most cases, violations will either not be triggered by a performance-oriented workload or will be ignored by Polygraph.`