# A Test For HTTP 1.1 Compliance

Tags: http, testing, automated-tests, protocols, standards-compliance

I wonder if there is a piece of software to allow automatically testing a webserver for compliance with the HTTP protocol? Ideally I'd like this program to work like this: I give it the address and port, it runs a bunch of requests and then outputs one of "non-compliant", "conditionally compliant", "fully compliant".

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only general HTTP test suite that I'm currently aware of is [CoAdvisor/HTTP](http://coad.measurement-factory.com/samples/http.html).

Afaik, you can have a free demo of it, but the demo contains only a *subset* of all the existing test cases they have. If you need more than that, check their license options.

Answer (score 0):

maybe `pathod` is some tool for you ? also, look for `libhtp` tests directory

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.